# What software packages have been used to produce the FCLA book and why that might be a more suitable choice than LaTeX?

Tags: book-design, xml

[A First Course in Linear Algebra (FCLA)](http://linear.ups.edu/index.html) was written in LaTeX until version 2.99 but switched to XML. See the [FCLA development page](http://linear.ups.edu/development.html) which contains a link to its git repository.

What set of softwares have been used to author and build the various versions of the book (different PDF and Web outputs)? What would be possible advantages of an XML-based markup over LaTeX?

Comment: Rather than ask here, wouldn't it be simpler to just send the author an email?

Comment: @AlanMunn I thought some other people might be interested in knowing the answer. This is fairly big project with a lot of cross refs. I am happy to delete the question if the community thinks this is not helpful in any way.

Comment: It's only marginally in topic and trivially answered by anyone who knows the book (or in my case just followed your link) by viewing the source .

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I (now) understand that the answer might be trivial. In my defence (if there is any room at all), I did look at quite a few XML files but missed the comment you mentioned. It was interesting to see someone has departed from LaTeX and has decided to use an XML-based markup instead. [update: I added this aspect to the question.]

Comment: @igor they use latex for typesetting. _lots_ of people use xml to generate tex for typesetting and html for the web as it's generally a much more controlled workflow than using tex directly and trying to generate html from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments in the files show

http://mathbook.pugetsound.edu/

is the convertor used from XML to the various formats.